# Reading specific CSV value in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I have the following CSV file:

```
08-0018421032;00-0018151831;G-20009429-0;G-20009429-0;0374048-0
27-001842101232;10-0018151831;G-30009429-0;G-50009429-0;7374048-0
36-0018421033232;20-0018151831;G-40009429-0;G-60009429-0;8374048-0
```

As you can see the separator is the ; symbol.

I then send this info to php via a jquery plugin which works perfect since I can read the file in PHP. The following code grabs the CSV file (Which is the $csvfile variable) and I can see the lines in it:

```
$file = fopen("upload/$csvfile", "r");
while (!feof($file) ) {
$line = fgetcsv($file, 1024,';');
print $line[0].'<br/>';
}
fclose($file);
```

What I need is to be able to select not only the line but on the value in it. To go to a specific value, for example in the first line the 3rd value would be **G-20009429-0** and I would assign this to a php variable to be used later on.

Right now I have no idea how to grab a specific value in a line  and also when I print the $line[0] it shows the values in a vertical order instead of a horizontal order. What I mean with this is that it shows the following output:

```
00-0018151831
10-0018151831
20-0018151831
```

Instead of showing me like this:

```
 08-0018421032;00-0018151831;G-20009429-0;G-20009429-0;0374048-0
```

Maybe is the sleep but am stuck here. Just to repeat, the csv file is read by Php correctly since I can do a print_r on it and it shows all the lines in it. The thing is how to manipulate the information after I have the csv and how to grab a specific value in a specific line. Thank you.

Comment: If all you want is the line itself why are you using `fgetcsv()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$line` is an array containing every element from that row. `$line[0]` is the first element of the row, `$line[1]` the second element and so on. Try `var_dump($line)`. What you're doing is you output every first element of every row.

If you want to output every element in one line, just concatenate the array again:

```
echo join(';', $line);
```

But then that's missing the point of `fgetcsv`, which is specifically helpfully separating those elements into an array for you so you can work with them.